# Maximize simulated likelihood in R -- is there something obvious I am not getting?

Tags: r, simulation, maximize, economics

I am trying to maximize a simulated likelihood in discrete choice (Lerman and Manski (1981)) by simulating frequencies and using them as probabilities (which I cannot compute directly). However, R never manages to find any optimum (maximization always yields starting values). As a minimal example, here my code for a very simple probit estimation:

```
### simulate data
set.seed(5849)
N <- 2000
b.cons  <- 8 
b.x         <- 10
x <- cbind(rep(1, N), runif(N)) #"observed variables"
e <- rnorm(N) # "unobserved error"
k <- runif(N)*10+7 # threshold: something random, but high enough to guarantee some variation in i
t <- x%*%c(b.cons, b.x)+e
i <- 1*(k>t) #participation dummy


### likelihood function
R   <- 1000 # number of draws
err <- matrix(rnorm(R*N), N, R) # draw error terms (outside of likelihood function to speed up estimation)

# estimate b.i, sig.i
probit.sim <- function(params, I, K, X) {
    part  =matrix(NA, N, R)
    T       = X%*%params%*%rep(1, R) + err
    for (i in 1:R) part[,i] = K>T[,i]

    pr.i1       = rowSums(part)/R
    pr.i1[pr.i1==0] <- 0.001 
    pr.i1[pr.i1==1] <- 0.999
    pr.i0       = 1-pr.i1

    llik = t(I)%*%log(pr.i1) + t(1-I)%*%log(pr.i0)
    -llik
}

### maximize likelihood
optim(c(1,1), probit.sim, I = i, K = k, X = x)
```

Is it because the probabilities are not smooth enough? Is there a way to maximize things that are not super smooth? On a graph, the maximum still seems pretty clear to the eye... Or am I missing something completely else?

I am really very much of a beginner, so I thank you in advance for any helpful advice!

(Also any reference that actually goes into the details of how to program such a simulated max likelihood function -- most references I saw remain very much theoretical about it)

Comment: (1) set the seed at the beginning for reproduciblity.  (2) Please do not post `rm(...)` lines.  (3) `set.seed(123); ...your code...; optim(c(1,1), probit.sim, I = i, K = k, X = x)` converges when I try it.

Comment: sorry for these mistakes in my "minimal code", i edited it accordingly. 

i already tried optim before and somehow it didn't work (well.) now, i still do not get the expected parameters (8, 10) even though i get something different from the starting values.

Comment: oh, and i just noticed (and corrected) a very stupid other mistake (very sorry).

Comment: Use better starting vaules, e.g. `st <- coef(lm(k*(1-i) ~ x-1)); optim(st, probit.sim, I = i, K = k, X = x)`

Comment: Somehow this solved the problem pretty neatly. Weird, as I tried something pretty similar before... Thanks a lot though.